# 1 Tomcat with 50GB of Ram or 20 tomcat with 2.5GB of Ram each?

Tags: web-server, java, deployment, memory-usage

My client has a Windows 2008 webserver with 64GB memory.

I have to deploy my company's system (that runs on Java) onto the server and connect to their existing Itanium database.

There is a reason why such a big memory is allocated it is because our system utilizes a large amount of memory where information written to the database, yet data is kept in  memory for fast access. A product similar to EHCache.

Past experience raises a concern:

> "In order for Java to work efficiently, each Java instance should be
>   keep around 2GB, else the Java Garbage Collector activity will kill
>   the response time"

Is the above concern still true with the latest JDK 1.6, or does this apply any more?

While I was working with JDK 1.4, I mitigated the java memory sizing limitation by deploying a few webservers with memory no more than 2GB.

Should I run just one large server or multiple servers each with ~2GB or RAM available?

Comment: You should benchmark *your* application in *your* environment rather than hoping for the experiences of others to be the same.

Comment: @womble the server is still in paper to date. I am to propose a deployment strategy in the mean time.

Comment: Proposed deployment strategy: "I will benchmark the following scenarios, testing them each by doing <x>, collecting statistics <y>, and making my decision based on <z>".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a mixed of both your options. Just imagine restarting the fat tomcat, it will generate some downtime and slowness when is getting back.

I suggest you to keep stable apps in one tomcat with more memory and the other that require more attention/frequent changes to be separated.

In other words, the approach should be driven by stability/service quality  and not by commodity (imagine restarting 20 tomcats).